# JavaScript context translate doesnt work in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, html5-canvas, electron

I am using `ctx.translate(x, y)` to move Camera in canvas game. But for some reason, that doesn't work.

This is what I am using:

```
setCameraPos: function(x, y) {
        //ctx.save()
        ctx.translate(x, y)
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
        //ctx.restore()
}
```

It doesn't work at all. It does not change position of camera.
Any errors? No errors at all.
I am using `Electron 3.0.3 Beta`.

**I accept any libraries**.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('main')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')


ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 30, 30)
// This doesn't work | VVV
ctx.translate(20, 20)
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="main">

</canvas>
```

Comment: It would be useful if you would show an example with actual canvas content, and describe what you mean with "It doesn't work".

Comment: Changed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The `setTransform` overwrites any previous transforms, like `translate`

Comment: Please note that all the transformations are effective on future draw operations and not on past ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you gave, the translate operation won't work anywhere, not just in Electron.

`ctx.setTransform()` method sets the transformation matrix to *absolute* values, the current matrix is discarded and the passed values are the ones to which your matrix will get set.
`1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0` are the values of the native matrix transform (i.e untransformed).

So calling `ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)` will reset your tranform matrix to its default and make all calls to relative *translate()*, *rotate()* or *transform()* useless.

These methods are meant to be relative because they add up to the current matrix values. For instance,

```
ctx.translate(10, 10);
// here next drawing will be offset by 10px in both x and y direction
ctx.translate(40, -10);
// this adds up to the current 10, 10, so we are now offset by 30, 0
```

If you want your *translate* to work, don't call setTransform here, or even replace it with `setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 20, 20)`

Also, in your snippet, you are setting the transformation matrix **after** you did draw. The transformations will get applied only on next drawings, not on previous ones.

Now, you might be in an animation loop, and need your matrix to get reset at every loop.
In this case, call `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` either at the beginning of your drawing loop, either as the last op, and call *translate()* before drawing.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('main');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let x = 0;
ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
anim();

function draw() {
  // reset the matrix so we can clear everything
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //set the transform before drawing
  ctx.translate(x - 30, 20)
  //which is actually the same as 
  //ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, 20);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 30, 30);
}
function anim() {
  x = (x + 2) % (canvas.width + 60);
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="main"></canvas>
```

Comment: But removing ctx.setTransform glitches canvas.

Comment: @Mr.DeleteMyMessages What do you mean? There is no reason you get any glitches, also, since your edit I saw you were drawing **before** setting the matrix-transform, feels like your question misses some important clues...

Comment: Everytime you do ctx.transform it adds value a to x and value b to y.

Comment: yes ctx.transform is "relative", it adds to the current value, setTransform is *"absolute"* it sets to this value.